# how to do a python request get command with bearertoken?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to do a python request get command using python. I have:

```
endpoint = https://eventsapi.uatxyzreports.com/api/v1/Events/OR/12345 
headers = {"Authorization":"abcxyz12345"}
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers = headers)
```

the response code is ("401")
but when I put in the same token I got a response code of 200. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: I believe you need the word "bearer" in there, e.g.: `{"Authorization": "Bearer abcxyz12345"}`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I added Bearer to the token and ow I am getting (500) but I believe it is because server issue. when it is getting server back on line, it should work.

Comment: Ok, let us know please so if it doesn't we can look at it further; and best wishes with the project.